# trouble porting RGB2CMYK method from c++ to java

Tags: java, c++, opencv

I am trying to convert a method from c++ to java. Here is the method:

```
void rgb2cmyk(cv::Mat& src, std::vector<cv::Mat>& cmyk)
{
    CV_Assert(src.type() == CV_8UC3);

    cmyk.clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
       cmyk.push_back(cv::Mat(src.size(), CV_32F));

    for (int i = 0; i < src.rows; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < src.cols; ++j)
        {
            cv::Vec3b p = src.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j);

            float r = p[2] / 255.;
            float g = p[1] / 255.;
            float b = p[0] / 255.;
            float k = (1 - std::max(std::max(r,g),b));

            cmyk[0].at<float>(i,j) = (1 - r - k) / (1 - k); 
            cmyk[1].at<float>(i,j) = (1 - g - k) / (1 - k);
            cmyk[2].at<float>(i,j) = (1 - b - k) / (1 - k);
            cmyk[3].at<float>(i,j) = k;
        }
    }
}
```

Problem is with the methods of OpenCv. Here is some detail:

1. I didn't find `CV_Assert` method in java. dont know any alternate
   for that.
2. `cmyk.push_back` is replaced with `cmyk[i].pushback`
3. i have used `Mat` replacing `cv::Vec3b`, it is shows no error
4. `std::max` is replaced with `Math.max`
5. issue is assignment to `cmyk[0].at<float>(i,j)`

Do any one have suggestion or any better approach of changing this method to java.

Thanks in advance for help....

**Edit**

What i did

```
public void rgb2xmyk(Mat src,Mat[] cmyk)
{
    //CV_Assert(src.type() == CV_8UC3);
    //cmyk.clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
        cmyk[i].push_back(new Mat(src.size(), CvType.CV_32F));

    for (int i = 0; i < src.rows; ++i)
    {
         for (int j = 0; j < src.cols; ++j)
         {
             double[] p = src.get(i,j);
             float r = (float) (p[2] / 255.);
             float g = (float) (p[1] / 255.);
             float b = (float) (p[0] / 255.);
             float k = (1 - Math.max(Math.max(r,g),b));

             cmyk[0].at<float>(i,j) = (1 - r - k) / (1 - k); 
             cmyk[1].at<float>(i,j) = (1 - g - k) / (1 - k);
             cmyk[2].at<float>(i,j) = (1 - b - k) / (1 - k);
             cmyk[3].at<float>(i,j) = k;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show your attempt (the non-working Java code)?

Comment: @Banex i have added Edit secion in my original post. please check. thanks

Comment: 1) you can use [assert](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/assert.html) or `if` + `throw exception`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must make sure that cmyk array of Mat has size=4. 
In the for loop, I suggest you use setTo:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    cmyk[i].setTo(new Mat(src.size(), CvType.CV_32F));
```

in the nested for loops, where you fill your cmyk, I would use put method

```
cmyk[0].put(i,j,new Float[] {(1 - r - k) / (1 - k)});
cmyk[1].put(i,j,new Float[] {(1 - g - k) / (1 - k)});
cmyk[2].put(i,j,new Float[] {(1 - b - k) / (1 - k)});
cmyk[3].put(i,j,new Float[] {k});
```

...hope this helps

Comment: i also have another line, from which i have trouble in moving to java. Sorry i never actually worked on c++ this is why i am having trouble in porting some lines. here is the line `im1 = cmyk[3].mul(1 - cmyk[1]) > 0.25;` where `im1` is `Mat` and `cmyk` is array of `Mat` type...
if you please guide me. thanks

Comment: cmyk[3].mul(1 - cmyk[1]) would be
`Mat tmp;`
`Core.subtract(Mat.ones(cmyk[1].size(), cmyk[1].type()), cmyk[1],tmp);`
`im1 = cmyk[3].mul(tmp);`
what '...>0.25' means, I have no idea. @SaghirA.Khatri

Answer (score 7):

You might find on this line:

```
cmyk[0].at<float>(i,j) = (1 - r - k) / (1 - k);
```

That the result is being processed as int before being cast to float, because you have integers starting each block. Try:

```
cmyk[0].at<float>(i,j) = (1.0f - r - k) / (1.0f - k);
```

I think you already have a sensible answer for how to access elements in that array though (via .put).

Comment: i also have another line, from which i have trouble in moving to java. Sorry i never actually worked on c++ this is why i am having trouble in porting some lines. here is the line im1 = cmyk[3].mul(1 - cmyk[1]) > 0.25; where im1 is Mat and cmyk is array of Mat type... if you please guide me. thanks